# ui form data not getting saved

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, ui-form

I have created a UI form in admin but I am not able to receive form data in save controller.
Following is my code in ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">my_edit_form.edit_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Anshu\MyManagement\Block\Adminhtml\My\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="Anshu\MyManagement\Block\Adminhtml\My\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>my_edit_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>myManagement</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>my_edit_form.edit_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="edit_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="my/my/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Anshu\MyManagement\Model\DataProvider" name="edit_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Information</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">myManagement</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="description" formElement="textarea">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">myManagement</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Description</label>
                <dataScope>description</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple **`field name="description"`**?

Comment: try changing `<dataScope>myManagement</dataScope>` to `<dataScope>data</dataScope>`

Comment: Can you please add your save controller code here?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I have added that by mistake, I have removed that now.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, that worked. It would be helpful if you can explain the purpose of the dataScope and data as its value or if you can share any link where I can go through to read about the fields in ui form components.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it properly. All I know is that in the core forms this is the value used everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Marius comments, I have changed `<dataScope>myManagement</dataScope>` to `<dataScope>data</dataScope>` and now form data is getting passed to save controller.